# Git: branch merge issue

Tags: git

I have created two branch: branch1 and branch2.
i have changed one file and commit into branch1 without merge in branch2. so at this level branch2 has not that commit.
now without merge branch1 into branch2, by mistakenly i commit one additional commit in branch2 .

so now i just want to this branch2 last commit changes in branch1 without losing branch1 last commit which is not available in branch2.

Is there any idea how can i solve ?

any idea helpful for me. thanks

Comment: Just create a copy of your current project before trying this. Well if you have the commit id's then you can revert back the commit to previous commits. Create a new branch3, merge it with branch2.  In branch2 revert back to your previous commit and merge it with branch1 and then merge branch2 and 3. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You may cherry pick the `branch2` commit into `branch1`:

```
git checkout branch1
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of branch2 commit>
```

But assuming that both branches have diverged from each other by only one commit, you could also just merge `branch2` into `branch1`:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
```

This option might be less desirable if you were planning on doing a final merge from `branch2` into `branch1` at some later point.

Comment: Tim, i have already push my branch1 commit into live site. and branch2 commit is remain. so can i do this : "git checkout branch1" then  "git pull origin branch2" in live site. then after in my local i can do this command : git pull origin branch2.  so is this make sense to solve my issue ?

Comment: If you haven't pushed the changes in branch2 nothing will happen.

Comment: @yausername No, I disagree with you.

Comment: `git merge branch2` will work but `git pull origin branch2` will not because the commits have not been pushed to origin as per OP's comment  "i have already push my branch1 commit into live site. and branch2 commit is remain. "

Comment: @yausername Where in my answer did I suggest `git pull`?  Please refrain from commenting if you don't understand Git.